# Converting Pandas column data with np.where() not working as it should

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am using np.where() in combination with a Pandas DataFrame to keep the column as-is if it contains the phrase "no restriction", and make it a float if not. Here is my code:

```
main_df[col] = np.where(main_df[col].str.contains('no restriction', case=False, na=False, regex=False),
                        main_df[col],
                        main_df[col].apply(lambda x: float(x)))
```

Here is the error I am getting on a cell that contains the string "No restriction":

```
    140     main_df[col] = np.where(main_df[col].str.contains('no restriction', case=False, na=False, regex=False),    
    141                             main_df[col],
--> 142                             main_df[col].apply(lambda x: float(x)))


ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'No restriction'
```

It looks like the Series.str.contains() isn't detecting a cell that contains the string 'No restriction'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `main_df[col].apply(lambda x: float(x))` still converts the whole series, including `'no restriction'`, which obviously fails and throws that error. You can use `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'` option:

```
main_df[col] = pd.to_numeric(main_df[col], errors='coerce').fillna(main_df[col])
```

The question is why, though? You should not be mixing `float` with `str` in a column.

Comment: Ah gotcha, I guess my understanding of `np.where(cond, [x, y])` is flawed, I though it only applied the "y" if the condition is false.

I have a column of strings where some of the strings are actual numbers and should be converted to numbers.

Any idea on an alternative method to turn the string numbers into floats in the same column while keeping other non-numbers (like 'No restriction') as strings?

Comment: What I posted there should do what you asked. It's just that it's not practical to do so...